# "Help->install new software" fails to run from source code

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

my question is why Update manager fails with message: "Could not locate the running profile instance. The eclipse.p2.data.area and eclipse.p2.profile properties may not be set correctly in this application's config.ini file." when i run my application from source code only.
1.using eclipse indigo:
2. i do have VM argument
-Declipse.p2.data.area=C:\devApp\eclipse\eclipse-standard-kepler-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\p2

Comment: What do you mean by 'source code only'?

Comment: development environment

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to check "Support software installation in the launched application" under "Software Installation" in your run configuration's Configuration tab.

[image]